# Access SoftImage SDK XSi Constants in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to the SoftImage SDK so please excuse me if this is a simple question.

In the API document there are a list of constants for the message box, for instance the 'siMsgOk' stores the value of 1. But when I try to use it in the codes it says siMsgOK is undefined. I could use the integer instead but it's just bad practice, is there a library that I need to import or are these constants private that I will have no access to?

E.g.

response = XSIUIToolkit.MsgBox("Would you like to play?", 3 , "Christmas Cracker Time")
if response == siMsgOk:
 # Do something

This returns error saying siMsgOk is not defined.

SDK Guide
http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/softimage2012/en_us/sdkguide/index.html?url=si_om/siMsgButtonPressed.html,topicNumber=si_om_siMsgButtonPressed_html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just found the answer in XSI wiki

http://softimage.wiki.softimage.com/sdkdocs/script_python_HowDoIGetPythontoRecognizeXSIConstantsEnums.htm

```
# import Softimage constants module
from win32com.client import constants

# Then access them under constants
constants.siMsgYesNoCancel
```